# Plot gam spatial estimates over a map

Tags: r, spatial, ggmap, poisson, gam

I have imported Italy map with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv) 
library(ggmap) 
Country <- "Italy"

Get_Map_Country <-
  get_map(
      location = Country
    , zoom = 6
    , scale = "auto"
    , maptype = "satellite"
    , messaging = FALSE
    , urlonly = FALSE
    , filename = "ggmapTemp"
    , crop = TRUE
    , color = "color"
    , source = "google"
    , api_key
    )

Country1 <-
  ggmap(
      ggmap = Get_Map_Country
    , extent = "panel"
  #  , base_layer
    , maprange = FALSE
    , legend = "right"
    , padding = 0.02
    , darken = c(0, "black")
    )
```

Furthermore, I fitted a gam model in which the response is assumed to be Poisson 
and the predictors are longitude and latitude.

```
mod1 <- gam(Value ~ s(Longitudine, Latitudine), data = data2017, family = "poisson")
```

Now, how can I overlay the results to the ggmap above? 
For instance, I would like to obtain something like:

[image]

obtained by using the "mfasiolo/mgcViz" package installed with devtools from github

```
library(devtools) 
install_github("mfasiolo/mgcViz")
library(mgcViz) 

b <- getViz(mod1)

pl <- plot(sm(b, 1)) + l_fitRaster() + l_fitContour() 
pl
```

But good-looking (for publication), slightly transparent over the italian map.
If anyone knows a way to obtain this, I would be extremely grateful.

I am open to different but meaningful solutions. 
Thanks in advance.

Simple reproducible example

```
> y <- c(10,   1,   2,   2,   2,   0,  19,   3,  2,   1,   7,  16,   5, 
> 13,  81,   1,   9,  96,   2,   9,  3,   4,   0, 1,  12)
> 
> long <- seq(9, 13, length.out = 25) 
> 
> lat <- seq(38, 43, length.out = 25) 
> 
> mod1 <- gam(y ~ s(long, lat, k = 3), family = "poisson")
#Now, I need not overlay Country1 and something like plot(mod1)
```

Comment: Hello Martino. Welcome to SO. In short, yeas, you can do all the above.
Yet, for the community to help you please provide a reproducible example and tell us what packages you are employing. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Thanks for the suggestions !I tried!

Comment: is there a solution yet?

Comment: +geom_polygon(data = map_data ("world"), aes(x=long, y = lat,group=group),fill=NA,color="red",inherit.aes = F) should work, just filter map_data e.g. to focus on Italy before including into geom_polygon